# Copy files matching the names in a list of paths and paste them in one new folder?

Tags: file, command-line, path, directory

I'm working in a windows 7 machine and I'm trying to take all of the files matching the names in a list of file paths (I have the list saved as a csv, rda, and can make a txt file if needed). Ie: the list looks like:

```
Y:/iglgrelkgjkrle/originals/jsfhdjk.xls
Y:/iglgrelkgjkrddsle/ffhej/originals/jsfhdjk.xlsx
Y:/kssrldsse/ffhej/originals/jsfhdjk.xlt
Y:/blahblah/blah/blahhh/blahhhhhh/originals/blahahaha.pdf
```

...
...

And basically I want all of these files in this list copied to a new folder in a different location. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Almost any problem can be solved with a `FOR` statement in windows command processor. Using `for /f` we can search a list in a text document and for each item (This case; location) specified, can run a command to copy it to a new location.

For copying the file, `xcopy` will be very handy as it has many copy option switches we can use such as `/i /z /y`.

- **/I** - If in doubt always assume the destination is a folder
- **/Z** - Copy files in restartable mode. If the copy is interrupted part way through,
       it will restart if possible.
- **/Y** - Suppress prompt to confirm overwriting a file. (Use `/-Y` for reverse)

In the following commands bellow, `C:\list.txt` is used as an example. This is where you specify the location of your list file. This can support a wide range of file formats including `html`. It does not hurt to try your extensions.

For the place to output the copied files - `C:\CopyFolder` is an example of the location of the folder you wish to send them too. You can also send them to a local server via `\\server\folder\`.

**From command Line:**

```
for /f "delims=" %i in (C:\list.txt) do (xcopy "%i" "C:\CopyFolder" /i /z /y)
```

**From batch file:**

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\list.txt) do (xcopy "%%i" "C:\CopyFolder" /i /z /y)
```

---

If this has solved your issue, please don't forget to mark this response as solved. I will be happy to further explain any questions!

Comment: Several years later, the command line version worked like a charm.  Thanks!